# Solr returns empty result when one of fq(filter queries) consists from stopword

Tags: filter, solr, stop-words

1.Having the next list of filter queries I would like to get some result documents basing on them
[filter queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7TOF.png)

```
fq=(name_text_en_us:"microwave") & fq=(name_text_en_us:"with") & fq=(name_text_en_us:"sensor")
```

Full url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/master/select?_=15231231220790&fq=name_text_en_us:"microwave"&fq=name_text_en_us:"with"&fq=name_text_en_us:"sensor"&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json
```

I'm getting empty result. 
Unfortunately I can't merge all queries in one and have to use them in a separate way.
2. I understand that since one of the filter queries consists only from a stopword - i.e. word "with" it will be parsed by SOLR as an empty string and basing on that SOLR will filter out all documents and result will be empty. 
If I remove such query and leave other - SOLR returns several documents.

If there any way how I can configure SOLR to not take into account filter queries with stopwords and as a result after those get parsed and become an empty string.

In other words I would like SOLR to skip filter queries with empty string and return result basing on other from the list

Comment: Is there any reason why you've split the query into multiple filter queries instead of having a single filter query? (which would make the fq behave as a regular query when it comes to stopwords)

Comment: mostly historical reasons on the project..

Comment: firstly I would like to try to handle it using SOLR configuration if it will be possible, if it's not then change the logic